# Calculus II Cartesian Coordinate

Tags: calculus

The Cartesian coordinates of a point are (−1,−1). Find polar coordinates (r, θ) of the point, where
(a)      r > 0  and  0 ≤ θ < 2π.
(b)      r < 0  and  −2π ≤ θ < 0.

I got $$\sqrt(2),pi/4$$ and $$\sqrt(2),-pi/4$$
However, system gives 1/2 points for the part a and 0 for the part b. I imagine it is about the angle for the part a and for the part b probably I need to change the r value since r<0 but I don't know how to find a new value for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\sqrt 2, 5\pi/4)$
$(-\sqrt 2, -7\pi/4)$